List all explicitly requested packages in pip
I'm trying to get a list of all packages that I have explicitly requested be installed. I know that pip keeps track of this information, as running pip inspect returns, as part of its output, a full list of installed packages in JSON format, storing a boolean value "requested".
This is specified in the pip inspect report JSON specification, which links the requested property to the REQUESTED metadata file specified in PEP 376, which is mentioned as an aside at the end of the "The .dist-info directory" section of "Recording Installed Packages".
Here is an (abridged) example pip inspect output:
{
  "installed": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "metadata_version": "2.1",
        "name": "example",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        // ...
      },
      // ...
      "installer": "pip",
      "requested": true
    },
  ],
  // ...
}

I also know of pip list --not-required, but it cuts out all packages which are dependencies of others, regardless of whether or not it was initially installed as a dependency. I have verified that this is the case with multiple packages in my installation.
Is there any simple, preferably command-line-based, reliable method with which I can get a pip freeze-like list of explicitly installed packages? Thank you in advance.

I suppose the problem here is that your environment may inherit packages from the global environment, which may or not have been installed by you. In that case, what should this pip list --installed do? Anyway, if this doesn't exist (which I am afraid is the case, but I could be wrong), it should definitely exist in my view, as this would allow people to recover or build a requirements file based only on what they strictly needed. Although one usually goes the other way around, i.e. you define the dependencies in the requirements file, setup.py or pyproject.toml and then install.

That's why I like poetry and I think is vastly superior to pip. You do a poetry add <package> and not only it installs the packages but also adds it to the pyproject.toml, among many other advantages.

@nbro Good point. This is in my global environment, though, so that isn't of particular concern to me.

Use a script / function like:
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def pkg_requested_packages():
    """
    Retrieves a list of packages explicitly installed by the user,
    based on the 'REQUESTED' metadata flag.

    Returns:
        set: A set of package names explicitly requested.
    """
    
    import pkg_resources

    return {dist.project_name
            for dist in pkg_resources.working_set
            if dist.has_metadata('REQUESTED')}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(' '.join(pkg_requested_packages()))

